# PHP permission denied to readdir even though its the same user and group

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos, readdir

Ive created a folder in my Gnome Desktop called "olli" and put some files in there. The folder is owned by the user "olli" and group "olli"

I then run this script

```
<?php
    if ($handle = opendir('/root/Desktop/olli')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                echo "$entry\n";
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
   }
?>
```

To try and list the files in there but it just gives permission denied. Even though the script is being ran by the user olli and group olli ?

Do i have to set something else in order to get permission to read this directory ?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't matter what the `olli` directory's permissions are, a script running as olli:olli will **NOT** have the rights to access anything in `/root`.

What you've done is the equivalent of leaving a safety deposit box inside a bank vault wide open. The box is there for the taking, but you can't get into the vault to access the box in the first place.

Comment: Nice analogy, @Marc B.

Comment: So i would have to move the olli folder off root? Its only for my own use anyway so i wasn't worried about security nobody will ever access it.

Comment: `/home/olli/Desktop/olli` might be a logical choice.

Comment: Thanks, ive moved the folder olli to another dir and its working. Appreciate the help.